# Add separate Opera tag for the new Opera browser

Tags: discussion

Right now there is only opera-mini and opera-mobile tags. Can we add the opera tag for [the new Opera browser](http://www.opera.com/mobile/android) for Android (that uses WebKit)? I don't have the reputation to do it myself right now.

I've had to tag my questions with opera-mobile, even though they are about the new Opera/WebKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think we should create a tag for each and every app around – that's not the purpose of tags. IMHO for that new Opera browser, the more generic opera-mobile tag should be OK. You can still fine-tune with your question phrasing which variant you're using.

Comment: Yes, but we still have Opera Mini and Opera Mobile. We could merge them into one generic Opera tag, or use a generic browser tag? I'm using opera-mobile now anyway, so I guess my questions are OK.

Comment: I'm for merging. Both tags together have 30 questions (assumed none of them carries both tags already, which would make that number even lower). I will set up a corresponding Meta request, and link here.

Comment: Done, see: [Merge opera-mini into opera-mobile](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1751/16575)