# Merge opera-mini into opera-mobile

Tags: discussion, retag-request

As just pointed out by [Add separate Opera tag for the new Opera browser](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1749/16575), we currently have two Opera tags:

- [opera-mini](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opera-mini) × 17
- [opera-mobile](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opera-mobile) × 13

I not only see no good reason in creating a third Opera-tag, but rather suggest to merge the two. Target should be `opera-mobile` (for all "mobile Opera browsers" that's the most intuitive one). Optionally, `opera-mini` could be kept as synonym (to avoid having it re-created).

Comment: Why not just opera (as the site implies Android). The other 2 can be synonyms.

Comment: I don't know that I agree with this. The question that [sparked that first Meta post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69064/set-font-size-in-opera) itself illustrates a difference between Opera Mini and the new Opera browser. Tagging them generically seems like it could cause confusion. The apps are very similar, certainly, but not the same.

Comment: @eldarerathis I still don't think it's advisable to create tags for each and every app around. The count of questions using those tags to me are indicators of, how to put it, "not that high importance". Differences (aka "fine-tuning") could be pointed out literally in the question text instead. Tags shouldn't enable you to write your problem without text :)

Comment: I see no reason why tags should *not* be created per-app.  They're not a finite resource, at least not with a limit were going to run into.  You should provide some rationale here Izzy.

Comment: @MatthewRead my rationale is that most questions and their answers will be very likely to fit all variants. So finding your information using a search with tags is easier if they are "grouped" – especially if each tag will only be applied to a few questions, as we see in this example. Would it be different (e.g. each tag holding 100+ questions), I had not made this proposal.

Comment: I'd say that searching "opera" is easy enough if you want to cover all variants.

Comment: @MatthewRead that would give you all posts *mentioning* Opera (i.e. also those writing e.g. "looks fine with Opera"), which might not be what's intended. But OK, it was just a suggestion; if I'm the only one on this side of the river, I take a boat and come over to join you :) In other words: Feel free to reject if that's what the majority feels right.

Answer (score 2):

To provide what seems to be the majority answer at this point:

We'd prefer to have specific tags, since the questions can be searched generically in other ways.